# Break at address "0xXXXXXXX" with no debug information available, or outside of program code

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32cubeide, nucleo, program-counter

I am using STM32CUBEIDE with Nucleo_STM32F412ZG usb and when I debug it. It shows message shown below:
*"Break at address "0x8007d3a" with no debug information available, or outside of program code."*
I am just trying to blink LED example.
https://github.com/k-code/stm32f4-examples/tree/master/Task-1-Leds
I am new to this and would really appreciate any input. Thanks in advance!
**Console:**
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 6.0.0
Copyright (c) 2021, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
Persistent Mode            : Disabled
Logging Level              : 1
Listen Port Number         : 61234
Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
Verbose Mode               : Disabled
SWD Debug                  : Enabled
InitWhile                  : Enabled

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Shutting down...
Exit.

I checked this answer
[Break at address "0xXXXXXX" with no debug information available, or outside of program code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178120/break-at-address-0xxxxxxx-with-no-debug-information-available-or-outside-of-p#new-answer)
but this doesn't work for me.
[image: Nucleo_STM32F412ZG]

```html
13:49:22 **** Build of configuration Debug for project NewBlinky ****
make -j4 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/main.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/main.d" -MT"Core/Src/main.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/main.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.d" -MT"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.d" -MT"Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/stm32f4xx_it.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/syscalls.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/syscalls.d" -MT"Core/Src/syscalls.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/syscalls.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/sysmem.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/sysmem.d" -MT"Core/Src/sysmem.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/sysmem.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Zx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.d" -MT"Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/system_stm32f4xx.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -g3 -DDEBUG -c -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -MP -MF"Core/startup_stm32f412zgtx.d" -MT"Core/startup_stm32f412zgtx.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/startup_stm32f412zgtx.o" "../Core/startup_stm32f412zgtx.S"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "NewBlinky.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"C:\Users\yashj\STM32CubeIDE\workspace\NewBlinky\STM32F412ZGTX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="NewBlinky.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -L"C:\Users\yashj\STM32CubeIDE\workspace\NewBlinky\Core\startup_stm32f412zgtx.S" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
Finished building target: NewBlinky.elf
 
arm-none-eabi-size   NewBlinky.elf 
arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S  NewBlinky.elf  > "NewBlinky.list"
arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O binary  NewBlinky.elf  "NewBlinky.bin"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10988      20    2668   13676    356c NewBlinky.elf
Finished building: default.size.stdout
 
Finished building: NewBlinky.bin
Finished building: NewBlinky.list
 
 

13:49:30 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 8s.531ms)
```

Comment: Can you post your compiler output?

Comment: Dear Armandas , I have added the compiler output.

Comment: The debug information flag (-g3) is set, so I am out of ideas for this one.

Comment: Did you check whether the adress `0x8007d3a` is in your executable ? (see .map file)

Comment: if you click on signal handler on the left tab, you should be able to see where the last function call is made. perhaps an assembly function

Comment: Power Requirements of Nucleo STM32 were not met with older generation laptop USB. With newer laptop I am now able to debug and flash the kit.